# Big-O Notation of Anagram solution algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis

In *Solution 1: Checking Off* of [Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/AlgorithmAnalysis/AnAnagramDetectionExample.html), just beneath the *ActiveCode: 1* extract (included at the bottom of this post for reference), it is stated:

> each of the n characters in s1 will cause an iteration through up to n
>   characters in the list from s2.

...which to paraphrase (less succinctly), means "**each character** in s1 could result in **all characters** in s2 being inspected".

The following sentence states:

> Each of the n positions in the list will be visited once to match a
>   character from s1.

Firstly I'm unsure which list is being referred, I think it means the variable `alist`, i.e. `s2`. Is this correct?

> The number of visits then becomes the sum of the integers from 1 to n.

Secondly (and the real point of this post), if each item in the list (variable `alist`) is inspected for each character in `s1`, then why is this not simply O(n) = n^2 as per "nested loops"?  If n=5, then then sum(n) = 15, where as n^2 = 25.

I'm fine with simplifying the equation for summing 1 to n integers to get n^2, but I'm confused about how sum(5) = 15, whereas O(n) = n^2.

[image]

**ActiveCode: 1 Checking Off (active5)**

```
def anagramSolution1(s1,s2):
    alist = list(s2)

    pos1 = 0
    stillOK = True

    while pos1 < len(s1) and stillOK:
        pos2 = 0
        found = False
        while pos2 < len(alist) and not found:
            if s1[pos1] == alist[pos2]:
                found = True
            else:
                pos2 = pos2 + 1

        if found:
            alist[pos2] = None
        else:
            stillOK = False

        pos1 = pos1 + 1

    return stillOK

print(anagramSolution1('abcd','dcba')
```

**Edit to add**

Having written this out it struck me that perhaps dropping the `(1/2)` and `(1/2)n` from the formula to `sum(n)` is the reason for the difference of actually summing `n`, as opposed to just doing `n^2`.

To be absolutely clear, I understand the formula for summing `n` is `n^2` when *dropping the non-dominant terms*. What I don't understand is why we're summing `n` and not immediately and directly stating it is actually `n^2` as a result of the nested loop and this sentence:

> each of the n characters in s1 will cause an iteration through up to n
>   characters in the list from s2.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's be concrete. Suppose `s1 = 'abcd'` and `s2 = 'dcba'`.

For the `a` in `s1`, it will take 4 iterations to find the `a` in `s2`. 
For the `b` in `s1`, it will take 3 iterations to find the `b` in `s2`.
For the `c` in `s1`, it will take 2 iterations to find the `c` in `s2`.
For the `d` in `s1`, it will take 1 iteration to find the `d` in `s2`.

So in this case, it does take `sum(i)` for `i = 1,...,n` iterations.

Now some quiet meditation should convince you than if `s2` is an anagram of `s1`, it will again take exactly the same number of iterations; the summands will just appear in a different order. (After all, whatever is the first character in `s2` will only require 1 iteration to be found, the second character requires 2 iterations, etc.)

If `s2` is not an anagram of `s1`, then the algorithm will short-circuit when the first character not in `s2` is tested. So then the algorithm will take less than O(n^2) time. But in the worst case, the algorithm takes O(n^2) time.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I see the crucial difference between this algorithm and nested for loops is that the nested loop exists early. The concrete example was very helpful.